# Having trouble turning mbpfan into a system service

Tags: software-installation, services, mac-mini

I'm a beginning Ubuntu user following [this tutorial](https://ineed.coffee/3838/a-beginners-tutorial-for-mbpfan-under-ubuntu/) to enable fan management  with [mbpfan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mbpfan.8.html) on my Mac Mini 4.1 running Ubuntu 18.04.

I had good success initially and then got to the point of trying to turn mbpfan into a system service. The first glitch I hit was that no mbpfan.service file was present on my system after installation, so I just downloaded it [from GitHub](https://github.com/dgraziotin/mbpfan), uploaded it via SFTP to my download folder, and then copied it as instructed with `sudo cp mbpfan.service /etc/systemd/system/`.

But here's the result when I try to execute `sudo systemctl enable mbpfan.service`:

```
Synchronizing state of mbpfan.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mbpfan
Failed to enable unit: File mbpfan.service: Invalid argument
```

I'm kind of stuck at this point and would appreciate a nudge. Thank you.

= = = = = = = = =

Edit 1:

`~$ systemctl status mbpfancs.service`

Produced:

```
mbpfancs.service - mbpfan Custom Service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mbpfancs.service; disabled; vendor preset
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-28 10:57:08 UTC; 27s ago
Process: 8521 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mbpfan -f (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 8521 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: Starting mbpfan Custom Service...
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: mbpfancs.service: Main process exited, code=
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: mbpfancs.service: Failed with result 'exit-c
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: Failed to start mbpfan Custom Service.`
```

And so then

`~$ journalctl -xe`

```
Sep 28 09:10:19 macmini dbus-daemon[1048]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 28 09:10:19 macmini systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-hostnamed.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-hostnamed.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Sep 28 09:10:19 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 09:10:19 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.host.services] Update service information
Sep 28 09:10:19 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 09:10:19 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.utils.gdbus] Call org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.L
Sep 28 09:17:01 macmini CRON[2158]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 28 09:17:01 macmini CRON[2159]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 28 09:17:01 macmini CRON[2158]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 09:50:53 macmini systemd-timesyncd[548]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Sep 28 09:50:53 macmini systemd-timesyncd[548]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Sep 28 10:17:01 macmini CRON[5657]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 28 10:17:01 macmini CRON[5658]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 28 10:17:01 macmini CRON[5657]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 10:36:59 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 10:36:59 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.updater] Fetch update data from https://version.home
Sep 28 10:36:59 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 10:36:59 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.store.git] Update add-on https://github.com/home-ass
Sep 28 10:36:59 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 10:36:59 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.store.git] Update add-on https://github.com/danimtb/
Sep 28 10:36:59 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 10:36:59 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.store.git] Update add-on https://github.com/hassio-a
Sep 28 10:37:00 macmini hassio-supervisor[9614]: 19-09-28 10:37:00 INFO (MainThread) [hassio.store] Load add-ons from store: 61 all - 0 new - 0 r
Sep 28 10:56:04 macmini sudo[8465]:    grant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/grant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/mbpfancs.service
Sep 28 10:56:04 macmini sudo[8465]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by grant(uid=0)
Sep 28 10:56:49 macmini sudo[8465]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini sudo[8518]:    grant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/grant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mbpfancs
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini sudo[8518]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by grant(uid=0)
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: Starting mbpfan Custom Service...
-- Subject: Unit mbpfancs.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mbpfancs.service has begun starting up.
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini mbpfan[8521]: mbpfan starting up
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini mbpfan[8521]: A previously created .pid file exists at: /var/run/mbpfan.pid. Aborting
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: mbpfancs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: mbpfancs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini systemd[1]: Failed to start mbpfan Custom Service.
-- Subject: Unit mbpfancs.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mbpfancs.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Sep 28 10:57:08 macmini sudo[8518]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1061-1108/1108 (END)
```

= = = = = = = = =

Edit 2:

```
~$ systemctl status mbpfancs.service
● mbpfancs.service - mbpfan Custom Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mbpfancs.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: activating (start) since Sat 2019-09-28 12:17:54 UTC; 2h 41min ago
 Main PID: 13324 (mbpfan)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mbpfancs.service
           └─13324 /usr/sbin/mbpfan -f

Sep 28 12:17:54 macmini systemd[1]: Starting mbpfan Custom Service...
Sep 28 12:17:54 macmini mbpfan[13324]: mbpfan starting up
```

Comment: You may find http://allanmcrae.com/2010/05/simple-macbook-pro-fan-daemon/ useful.

Comment: Please run `which mbpfan` in the terminal and [edit] your question with the output. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom service as explained below.

You will, however, need to know the exact path to the `mbpfan` executable on your system. To do so, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
which mbpfan
```

You will get an output like this:

```
/usr/sbin/mbpfan
```

Copy the output and replace `PATH_TO_MBPFAN` in the service file below with it. Then, please proceed with the instructions below.

---

**Firstly,** create and edit a custom systemd service for `mbpfan` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mbpfancs.service
```

**Secondly,** copy and paste the following code into the editor replacing **`PATH_TO_MBPFAN`** with the output of `which mbpfan` and save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

```
[Unit]
Description=mbpfan Custom Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=PATH_TO_MBPFAN -f

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Thirdly,** start the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start mbpfancs
```

**Fourthly,** enable the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable mbpfancs
```

**Finally,** reboot your system.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got to the point of starting the service:

`~$ sudo systemctl start mbpfancs`

And received 

`Job for mbpfancs.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mbpfancs.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I would provide the results of `~$ systemctl status mbpfancs.service` except that I seem to be limited in the number of characters for my reply. I'm sure it's my unfamiliarity with the forum, so my apologies.

Comment: I went ahead and rebooted, and then I tried `sudo systemctl start mbpfancs` again. That seems to have worked -- the fans spun down to a normal level -- but the CLI hung at that point. Not sure if that's relevant. After ^C I went ahead and did `sudo systemctl enable mbpfancs` and received confirmation that a symlink had been created. So maybe everything's OK?

Comment: @GrantLewis Please add the output of `systemctl status mbpfancs.service` to your question by editing it.

Comment: I've done that. Thank you.

Comment: @GrantLewis Was the posted status before reboot?. If so, can you run it again now and update the post. Thank you

Comment: @GrantLewis `/run` directory is a temporary filesystem (tmpfs) which stores volatile run-time data. `/var/run` is the predecessor of `/run` and is kept for backwards compatibility but serves the same purpose. If `mbpfancs` service worked with no errors after reboot, then well done and all is OK. Never mind the errors before reboot as a process identifier seems to have been placed in `/var/run` (probably as a result of previous attempts) which was cleared after reboot.

Comment: I've posted the results after boot as Edit 2. It appears that everything is working. Thank you!

Comment: @GrantLewis Yep! `mbpfancs.service` looks well configured and good to go. You are most welcome