# 18.04: Macbook pro mid 2012 runs very hot

Tags: 18.04, macbook, temperature

I'm not doing anything but web browsing with Firefox, yet my MacBook Pro (ca. mid-2012) is very hot. I have 8GB of RAM so it's not a problem. There is about 5GB available at the moment. I tried a couple of solutions but they haven't worked. This is pretty annoying as I continue to have problems with 18.04.

`user1@ubuntu:~$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
37200
81000`

The MacBook Pro has an Intel Core i5 running at 2.5 GHz, 8GB RAM, a 500 GB SSD, and uses Intel HD Graphics with 1.5GB  RAM.

`lshw -c video | grep configuration` shows

> configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

`lspci | grep VGA` shows

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
>   processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Subsystem: Apple Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Isn't there an Nvidia too? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: If there is no Nvidia, then the laptop should be cleaned of dust inside.

Comment: @Pilot6 added. I have a dual boot of macos and 18.04 and haven't had any problems with the temperature when using macos so I don't think the dust is the problem.

Comment: Related: [Having trouble turning mbpfan into a system service](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177173/968501)

Comment: @Raffa the fans don't seem to be the problem. It's rather that the CPU is very hot and the fans work just fine. Changing how the fans operate won't fix the problem.

Comment: Then probably give `TLP` a try. You can install it following instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160001/968501)

Comment: @Raffa I downloaded TLP right when you posted and waited to see if there are any changes but I it's still really hot and the fan comes up even when I have 6GB Ram free.