# Cannot login to Ubuntu 18.04 after nvidia

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xubuntu, macbook

My Mac started to heat up fast after installing Ubuntu.

I looked at this thread [Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac gets too hot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644907/ubuntu-14-04-on-mac-gets-too-hot) and used this line in the terminal.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime`.

I then rebooted. But all I can see when I start Ubuntu is this:

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1163516/968501 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1177173/968501

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)

Comment: Is this safe to follow when I’m using Ubuntu on partition? Dual boot on Mac

Comment: And I'm using MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: The instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) should help you install the right graphics card drivers for your system and should only affect Ubuntu not mac

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try your instructions

Comment: I have tried the first step (hold down shift key) several times but is still get the blinking screen). When I start my Mac, I first see the booting screen to choose Ubuntu  or iOS. When I press shift right after I choose Ubuntu or even before, I still get the blinking screen. Am I doing it the correct way?

Comment: It is a bit tricky :) . Please read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and keep trying.

Comment: This Mac doesn't have NVIDIA. Anyway, install 19.10. next month it will be an easy upgrade to 20.04, and meanwhile you get a better kernel

Comment: I still cannot get into recovery mode when I'm using rEFInd. I'm thinking about reinstall macOS and delete my partitions. I can then try to make a new partition and install ubuntu 19