# MacMini 2010 with Ubuntu 22.04 - temperature problems (Fan Control)

Tags: 22.04, temperature, fancontrol, mac-mini

I have a mac mini 2010 (4.1), with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and the temperature control doesn't work.

I tried installing mbpfan and it didn't work.
I tried installing macfanctld and it didn't work.
This is the result of sensors:

```
nouveau-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:    810.00 mV (min =  +0.81 V, max =  +0.90 V)
temp1:        +84.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +73.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +72.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Exhaust  :      0 RPM  (min = 1800 RPM, max = 5500 RPM)
TA0P:         +51.8°C  
TC0D:         +74.0°C  
TC0G:         +70.0°C  
TC0H:         +73.2°C  
TC0P:         +67.8°C  
TC0p:         +67.5°C  
TCPG:         +73.0°C  
TH0G:         +60.0°C  
TH0P:         +47.0°C  
TH0p:         +47.0°C  
TM0G:         +75.0°C  
TM0P:         +67.5°C  
TM0p:         +67.5°C  
TN0D:         +75.8°C  
TN0G:         +67.0°C  
TN0P:         +65.8°C  
TN0p:         +66.0°C  
TN1D:         +84.0°C  
TN1E:         +84.0°C  
TN1F:         +85.0°C  
TN1G:         +90.0°C  
TN1S:         +85.0°C  
TNPG:         +70.0°C  
TO0P:         +48.0°C  
TO0p:         +48.0°C  
TW0P:         +56.5°C  
Tm0P:         +61.2°C  
Tp0C:         +48.8°C
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1177173/968501

Comment: Can you run `mbpfan -f -v` and share the results?